# How do i specify page number and number of pages(size) to be shown for pagination?

Tags: angular, spring, api, angular7

What parameters should I add to show only pages from 0-5 on first load and then so on.

return this.http.post(environment.apisub + 'subscriptionPlan/getList', JSON.stringify(params), httpJSONOptions);

Eg. the url should be /subscriptionPlan?page=5

Answer (score -1):

Try to examine [angular material paginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview)

Comment: I have implemented that. This is the http post client where i want to send the page size in url. @Grzegorz Eleryk